# UIImageView corner radius results in gray unwanted sharp angle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I wonder why setting the corner radius of a ImageView will results in gray unwanted sharp angle, like this

[image]

Noted there is sharp gray angle behind the rounded corner image. 
I set up the corner radius like this:

```
 self.previewImageView.image = videoStream.thumbImage;
 self.previewImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
 self.previewImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
 self.previewImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

I also make sure the background color of the image view is white, but it wouldn't help anyway.

Anyone has any idea how to get rid of the sharp gray angle while setting the rounded corner of the image view?

I know I might draw a path and set the layer's mask path, are there any alternative?

My background view is a collection view cell, which happens to be not the same size as the imageView, i can't just set the corner radius of my background view

Comment: Make sure that your image don't have that gray border by default. Try opening it on browser or anywhere and check once.

Comment: No, it does not have

Comment: Which view is behind the UIImageView and what is its color ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the image view's background color to clear.

Comment: I tried `self.previewImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

just do:-

```
self.yourBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius=self.yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius
```

Comment: My background view is a collection view cell, which happens to be not the same size as the imageView, i can't just set the corner radius of my background view

Comment: apply corner radius to the collectionviewcell than simple as that : ).

Comment: I said the cell is not just occupied by the imageView. Say the cell is 100 * 120, the image is 100 * 100, aligning top and leading, you can't just set the corner radius of the cell, it only works for the upper top two corners, while the bottom corner of the imageView remains intact.

Comment: without the code it is impossible to tell whats wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code --

self.previewImageView.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor clearColor]);

Hope this one is helpful.